# How to solve the matrix equation $ AXA^H+\rho X = B $ for $X$, efficiently

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going to solve the following linear equation
$$
AXA^H+\rho X = B
$$
where $A,B$ are the known matrices, $\rho$ is a known scale parameter, and $X$ is a matrix to be solved.

This linear equation can be solved by transforming it as
$$
(A^*\otimes A+ \rho I)\text{vec}(X)  = \text{vec}(B)
$$
where $A^*$ is the conjugate matrix of $A$. However, this approach is definitely time-consuming. Is there any much more efficient solutions for such a linear problem.

Comment: What do we know about $A,B,\rho$? If $\rho < 0$, then this is can be written as a [discrete time Lyapunov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation), for which dedicated methods exist in Matlab and python. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then the equation can be solved in $O(n^3)$ operations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, in my case $\rho \ge 0$ and $A,B$ are some randomly generated matrices. In such a situation, is this linear equation can be solved more efficiently?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are really randomly generated in any conventional sense, then we can guarantee with high probability that $A$ will be diagonalizable, which means that the second option should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable (which, if $A$ is randomly generated as you state in your comment, should be true with high probability). Let $S$ be an invertible matrix such that $A = SDS^{-1}$, where $D$ is diagonal. Note that
$$
AXA^H = (SDS^{-1})X(SDS^{-1})^H = S[D(S^{-1}XS^{-H})D]S^H.
$$
With that, rewrite the equation as
$$
AXA^H + \rho X = B \implies\\
S[D(S^{-1}XS^{-H})D]S^H + \rho X = B \implies\\
D(S^{-1}XS^{-H})D + \rho(S^{-1}XS^{-H}) = S^{-1}BS^{-H}.
$$
With that, we can make the substitution $Y = S^{-1}XS^{-H}$ and thereby break the solution of the problem into two steps. First, solve for $Y$ in the equation
$$
DYD + \rho Y = M,
$$
where $M = S^{-1}BS^{-H}$. If $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ denote the diagonal entries of $D$, then this equation can be solved explicitly as follows. For each $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, we have
$$
\lambda_i\lambda_j y_{ij} + \rho y_{ij} = m_{ij} \implies y_{ij} = \frac{m_{ij}}{\rho + \lambda_i\lambda_j}.
$$
Note that this system will only have a unique solution if there are no eigenvalues $\lambda_i,\lambda_j$ of $A$ for which $\lambda_i \lambda_j = -\rho$.

For the second step, simply compute $X = SYS^H$.